# How can I combine Logout \ Login buttons in the same jsp page by session?

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, scriptlet

I'm trying to put this scriptlet code inside my jsp page.

```
<%
if(session.getAttribute("UserName").toString().equals(null) || session.getAttribute("UserName").toString().equals(""))
    out.println("<input type='button' id='Loginbtn' name='Loginbtn' value='Login' onclick='Alert.render()' style='height: 25px; width: 55px'>");
else
    out.println("<form method='POST' action='Logout'><strong><input type='submit' value='Logout' id='LogoutSubmit' name='LogoutSubmit' style='height: 25px; width: 55px'></strong></form>");
%>
```

The problem is- only the else block is working each time, even when I'm switching the out.println printings, the login works properly, but only the else block.

I also have tried to close the script location before the printings (combined script and jsp) and put the jsp code directly. only the else block worked either.

Why is that? And how can I switch between Login and Logout buttons based on if there is a session or not?

Comment: `session.getAttribute("UserName").toString()` this code is not looking good, its candidate for NPE. Instead use EL with JSTL tags like `<c:choose><c:when test='${empty session.UserName}'>Login</c:when><c:otherwise>Logout </c:otherwise></c:choose>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm not familiar with that.
How should I write this script in <script></script> block? in the middle of jsp page?
I have tried- and it just didn't print me a thing.
I also tried simply '<c:out value="${session.UserName}"/>'
and it didn't work for me either.
How it supposed to be written?

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

`if(session.getAttribute("UserName").toString().equals(null)` will throw the null pointer exception if its null because you can't use dot operator on null.

You can just use `if(session.getAttribute("UserName")==null` because null is the same whether the variable is a String or Object.

But I would suggest pulling the values out of session to variables first:

```
String username = (String)session.getAttribute("UserName");
if(username!=null && !"".equals(username.trim()))
{
```